# How to use styled components with Material UI input?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a slight problem with Material UI input, I want to change the design of it using styled components, but I came across an issue. This is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Input from "@mui/material/Input";
import InputAdornment from "@mui/material/InputAdornment";
import { BiSearch } from "react-icons/bi";

const InputContainer = styled(Input)`
    width: 350px;
    height: 42px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
`;

const SearchIcon = styled(BiSearch)`
  color: #c0c0c0;
  margin-left: 14px;
`;

const InputComponent = ({ placeholder, type }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <InputContainer
        placeholder={placeholder}
        startAdornment={
          type === "Search" ? (
            <InputAdornment position="start">
              <SearchIcon size="20" />
            </InputAdornment>
          ) : (
            ""
          )
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputComponent;
```

What I want to do:

1. Change placeholder size
2. When user hovers or clicks on input there is no bottom border like there is now, basically I want to remove bottom border

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Change placeholder size

For this, you can target the input element and change the font size. e.g.

```
const InputContainer = styled(Input)`
  width: 350px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;

  input::placeholder {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
`;
```

> When user hovers or clicks on input there is no bottom border like
> there is now, basically I want to remove bottom border

For this, you can use the `disableUnderline` [prop](https://mui.com/api/input/). e.g the updated code will be

```
<InputContainer
    placeholder={placeholder}
    disableUnderline
    startAdornment={
      type === "Search" ? (
        <InputAdornment position="start">
          <SearchIcon size="20" />
        </InputAdornment>
      ) : (
        ""
      )
    }
/>
```